version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.8, need 8.6.9
My laptop python is 3.9.0
I created script.py and bundled it using pyinstaller.
inside script.py, I called a batch_file.bat that call A.py as below:
process = subprocess.Popen(batch_file.bat, env=env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

the batch_file.bat is calling A.py using python 3.7.2 because thats the project python version
%DIR_PYTHON_3_7_2%\python.exe %ITS_DIR%/A.py

after bundling it and running the script.exe,
This is the error message I got
  File "D:\Tool\Common\python\v3.7.2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 809, in figure
    FigureClass=FigureClass, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Tool\Common\python\v3.7.2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 325, in new_figure_manager
    return _get_backend_mod().new_figure_manager(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Tool\Common\python\v3.7.2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3494, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "D:\Tool\Common\python\v3.7.2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 949, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "D:\Tool\Common\python\v3.7.2\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    {C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI208802\tcl} C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI208802/tcl8.6 D:/Tool/Common/python/v3.7.2/lib/tcl8.6 D:/Tool/Common/python/lib/tcl8.6 D:/Tool/Common/lib/tcl8.6 D:/Tool/Common/python/library D:/Tool/Common/library D:/Tool/Common/tcl8.6.8/library D:/Tool/tcl8.6.8/library

C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI208802/tcl/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.8, need 8.6.9
version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.6.8, need 8.6.9
    while executing
"package require Tcl 8.6.9"
    (file "C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI208802/tcl/init.tcl" line 19)
    invoked from within
"source C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI208802/tcl/init.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]"


This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

Note that this issue does not happen if i run directly using script. it only happen after i bundle it.
I cannot downgrade my laptop python version because i need to use library with minimum python version 3.9.0
tried change version in init.tcl. not able to create the exe
also tried to downgrade python to 3.7.2. cannot 1 of library used need 3.9.0
play around with subprocess.run/pOpen. not working so far

It is better to use the embedded Python (by using sys.executable) inside the generated executable to execute A.py.

@acw1668 but that will use the current python version to run the file (python 3.9.0 in this case) but OP wants python 3.7.2 to run the file instead.

Sounds like it is somehow picking up a (bugfix-level) mismatch between the C library part of Tcl and the script library part. I don't know why the bundler is going wrong.
